Prime React: Ordenar columnas de fecha
Estoy tratando de ordenar mi datatable de primereact a una columna de Fechas sin embargo lo esta ordenando por los dias y no toma encuenta la fecha.
         <Column
            field="Date"
            header="Date"
            sortable={true}
            body={(rowData: any) => formatDate(rowData.Date)}
          />

Aqui estoy colocando el formato a la fecha
    export const formatDate = (date: any) => {
      if (!date) return '';
     return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        day: '2-digit',
        month: '2-digit',
        year: 'numeric',
        });
     };

Aqui es como se ve cuando lo trato de ordenar


ya probaste con dataType="date" en los atributos de tu columna?
